# Deleting folders VB

Tags: vb.net, directory, copy, winrar

I am making a program that will list mods in a game. Ive got the code for it down here. But the mod directory-location is not the proper way show it.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' make a reference to the mod folder
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("I:\Steam\steamapps\common\Kerbal Space Program\GameData")
        ' find the folders
        Dim diar1 As IO.DirectoryInfo() = di.GetDirectories()
        Dim dra As IO.DirectoryInfo
        ' find the files
        Dim diar As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim drag As IO.FileInfo

        ' make a list of all folders in the main folder
        For Each dra In diar1
            Liste.Items.Add(dra)
        Next
        ' make a list of all files in the main folder
        For Each drag In diar
            Liste.Items.Add(drag)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Liste.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

So instead of the whole directory-location being told to the listbox "I:\Steam\steamapps\common\Kerbal Space Program\GameData" It would automaticly find the \KSP\GameData directory. Could that be done? If so, could anyone explain, either with a snippet with code or just a simple explaining, how i could do this?

Bonus questions:

1. Could you use VB to copy a mod folder from a WinRar file over to the mod directory? If so, could anyone explain, either with a snippet with code or just a simple explaining, how i could do this?
2. Could i "disable" the mod folders, so the game wouldnt detect them, but could still be "enabled" again? (Instead of deleting the mod completely) If so, could anyone explain, either with a snippet with code or just a simple explaining, how i could do this?

I HAVE tried google, though i am searching for someone who could explain it to me.

Comment: "Could that be done?" -> yes. Bonus questions 1. -> yes. 2. -> yes. What did I win (I mean... with bonus questions and all I guess that I have won something)?

Comment: See... you have to make a small effort to ask properly here. Questions like "can this be done?" are rarely positive to your interests. Try to solve your problems by your own and, if you reach a point where you get stuck, ask about it, the more specific is your question, the better. Asking here shouldn't ever be the first alternative, but the last one (after work by your own, research, learning, more work, more learning, more work, more research, etc.).

Comment: [WinRAR and RAR archiver addons](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) page contains a link to free __UnRAR OCX control__ *for use within Visual Basic program* to extract files from a RAR archive to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Copying files out of a rar (or other compressed file) is possible, I've done it in Java, although I do not know how to do it in VB.

As for the second question, for disabling, just rename the folder (or even the individual mods themselves by giving them a different extension, e.g. `someMod.ext.disabled`).  That should be trivial.

Comment: By applying the idea of "you get what you deserve", this answer is perfect for the OP's question :)

Comment: I even spent 45 seconds trying to Google an answer.  Nothing floated to the top that was immediately usable.

Comment: The whole 45 secs!! I don't know perhaps my first impression wasn't too accurate. This seems already too much.

Comment: I figured I could at least point the fellow at a similar question.

Comment: Hey hey, easy now. I'm a beginner in the programming department. Sorry if i didn't search right on Google, but i didn't find anything that could explain the answer nor give any direction to what does what. But anyways, thanks for the answer Draco.

Comment: We're joshing around, @Thomsen1707 :)  You'll want to search along the lines of "uncompressing files with VB"

Comment: And that is for the WinRar question? Thanks, ill give it a go :)